# Simplify this expression with cos and sin

Tags: trigonometry

$$\dfrac{\cos 12x}{\cos 4x}-\dfrac{\sin 12x}{\sin 4x}=\dfrac{\cos^2 6x-\sin^2 6x}{\cos^2 2x-\sin^2 2x}-\dfrac{2\sin 6x \cos6x}{2\sin2x \cos2x}$$ What should I do next?

Comment: First format the equation using MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\cos 12x}{\cos 4x}-\frac{\sin 12x}{\sin 4x}=\frac{\sin 4x\cos 12x-\sin 12x\cos 4x}{\sin 4x\cos 4x}$$

$$=\frac{\sin(4x-12x)}{\frac{1}{2}\sin8x}=\frac{2\sin(-8x)}{\sin 8x}=\frac{-2\sin 8x}{\sin 8x}=-2$$

Answer (score 0):

You should first note that setting $4x=y$ gives
$$
\frac{\cos 12x}{\cos 4x}-\frac{\sin 12x}{\sin 4x}=
\frac{\cos3y}{\cos y}-\frac{\sin3y}{\sin y}
$$
Now you can make a common denominator and use the subtraction formula or recall that
\begin{align}
\cos3y&=4\cos^3y-3\cos y\\[3px]
\sin3y&=3\sin y-4\sin^3y
\end{align}
and the formula simplifies nicely

> $\displaystyle\frac{\cos3y}{\cos y}-\frac{\sin3y}{\sin y}=4\cos^2y-3-3+4\sin^2y=4(\cos^2y+\sin^2y)-6=-2$